# Reverse Engineering my App

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract Objective-c binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894666/extract-objective-c-binary)

My Xcode recently crashed and corrupted my project that contains my app. I am away from my time machine backup, and need to get the files back (if only the raw code). Is there any way to decompile my .app or simulator file to get the code back?

Comment: I can't think of a way that XCode will have damaged your source code - your project file will certainly have been damaged but the source itself? What exactly happened?

Comment: Other possible related question: [Is there a way to reverse engineer an Xcode project from a .app file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322996/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a part of the build process, Xcode compiles each source class into a `.o` file. There's no way to open these files, but you can use these complied classes as is.

if you can find the `.o` files or the `.a` library in your build folder, you can import them into a new Xcode project. You can also open those `.o` files in text editor and usually the object names are in the end. I've done something like that in order to "borrow" some complied code.

It's more an hack than a solution, and you should do it as a last resort only

Comment: @Till, thanks for fixing the extensions :-)

Comment: Well, Thank god for Time Machine!

Answer (score 0):

In a word "no". The source code is not in the binary app.